# Display message box before redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to promp the user that the transaction was sucessful. But what happening in here is before the message box has a chance to showup the page redirects to other page imediately? What code should i use?

Comment: Perhaps provide some code to accompany your question? Your question is not answerable in its current state.

Comment: Please [read this guide on how to structure a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to display alert first:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.GetType(),"redirect",
"alert('Time OutAlert'); window.location='" + 
Request.ApplicationPath + "Nextpage.aspx';",true);
```